# RegEx to parse lines between two strings in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a free form text file(Not XML) from which i would like to parse the lines between two patterns. Here is the sample data

```
<Hi>
col1 col2 col3
1 2 3 
4 5 6
helo how are 

<How>
col1 col2
1 2 
helo hi'
```

I want to parse the data between each tag i.e `<Hi>` and the `blank` line as a single string. Similarly the data between `<How>`  and the `blank` line as another string.

The regex pattern i tried so far did not work.

```
val pattern = "^<Hi>(.*)\\n"
val pattern = "^<Hi>(.*)\\s*$"
val pattern = "^<Hi>(.*)"
val pattern = "^<Network>(.*)((\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)$)|(^(\\r\\n|\\n|\\r))|^\\s*$"
```

Is there a way i can specify a pattern for the blank line. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a freeform text. Not an XML

Comment: I did mention. Thanks.

Comment: Try searching for the "DOTALL" modifier for regular expressions. Have a go with that and if you get stuck, update the question. Also, can you post the code that you are using to execute the regular expression and print the results.

Comment: You can try something like this `<Hi>([\s\S]+)(?=^$)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hryqmW/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead: `[^\>]+(?=\n{2,}|$|\<)`.
Remember to use the global flag to find all matches. 
You can take a look at the explanation here:

https://regexr.com/4e9c1

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex and capture your data from group1,

```
<[^>]+>\s*([\w\W]*?(?=\n\n|$))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fRzzGC/1/)**

**Explanation:**

- `<[^>]+>\s*` - Start capturing the tag using `<[^>]+>` and optional whitespace(s) with `\s*`
- `([\w\W]*?` - Capture any characters including newlines in non-greedy manner
- `(?=\n\n|$))` - Positive look ahead to ensure the match stops as soon as it sees two newlines or absolute end of string

Answer (score 3):

Solution in code.

```
val src = io.Source.fromFile("so.txt")

"(?s)>\\s*(.+?)(?=\n\n|$)".r
                          .findAllMatchIn(src.mkString)
                          .map(_.group(1))
                          .mkString("->", "<-\n->", "<-")
//res0: String =
//->col1 col2 col3
//1 2 3
//4 5 6
//helo how are <-
//->col1 col2
//1 2
//helo hi'<-

src.close()
```